# Get relief of Switzerland from a shp-file

Tags: r, gis, raster, shapefile

I would like an official source for drawing the relief over a map of Switzerland.

I downloaded https://cms.geo.admin.ch/ogd/topography/DHM25_BM_SHP.zip to use the dhm25_p.shp-File

Now using the code

```
aux <- st_read(dsn="dhm25_p.shp")
auxx <- as_Spatial(aux)
auxxx <- as.data.frame(auxx)

ggplot() +
  
  # draw the relief
  geom_raster(
    data = auxxx,
    inherit.aes = FALSE,
    aes(
      x = coords.x1,
      y = coords.x2,
      alpha = coords.x3
    )
  )
```

I'll get the error

```
Error in `geom_raster()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error:
! cannot allocate vector of size 6539542.5 Gb
```

Comment: Being a shapefile (.SHP) it contains some vector representation of the height model (perhaps contourlines). `geom_raster` might try to rasterize these, perhaps even at a 1x1 m² resolution, thus exceeding the maximum memory available. You could try `geom_sf(data = aux)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. Now I get a map, but unfortunately mostly black - with the exception of the lakes. Can it be that the resolution is too high, so that I can't see the details and if yes, how can I reduce it?

Comment: Stupid question: Why don't you simply use the DHM25 elevation model provided [here](https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/geodata/height/dhm25200.html) instead of rasterizing ~200k points yourself?

Comment: @MPB: as dimfalk pointed out, that shape is 210k point data, not contours (as I had suspected). In that case, you could first interpolate altitudes at a coarser grid (e.g. with `interp::interp()` and then use `geom_contour()` ... but these data seem available already (see dimfalk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shapefile of points is generally not a good source for mapping continuous phenomena such as elevation. It is better to use raster data.

Here is a simple way to make an elevation map for Switzerland

```
library(terra)
library(geodata)
x <- geodata::elevation_30s("Switzerland", ".")
plot(x)
```

Add contour lines

```
v <- as.contour(x, levels=c(500,1000,3000))
lines(v)
```

Or show shaded relief

```
slope <- terrain(x, "slope", unit="radians")
aspect <- terrain(x, "aspect", unit="radians")
hill <- shade(slope, aspect, 40, 270)
plot(hill, col=gray(seq(0,1,.01)), legend=F, axes=F, mar=1)
```

To show relief and elevation

```
plot(hill, col=gray(seq(0,1,.01)), legend=F, axes=F)
plot(x, col=terrain.colors(25, alpha=.5), add=T, axes=F, legend=T)
```

[image]

You can do the same things with the Swiss government data from the [website](https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/geodata/height/dhm25200.html%20an) you point to in your (now hidden) answer. But it takes some more work if you want to remove the areas outside of Switzerland.

```
y <- rast("DHM200.asc")
# Assign the coordinate reference system (Landesvermessung 1903)
crs(y) <- "EPSG:21781" 

# get the outline of the country and project it to the crs of the raster data 
swz <- geodata::gadm("Switzerland", level=1, path=".")
pswz <- project(swz, y)

# remove values for areas outside of Switzerland
y <- mask(y, pswz)

plot(y)
lines (pswz)
```

And with ggplot you can use `geom_spatraster`

```
library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_spatraster(data = y)
```

Comment: Great - thanks! In addition: how is it possible to combine the hillshaded version with the original plot: 1) ggplot() +  geom_spatraster(data=hill) + scale_fill_hypso_c() results in a nice hillshaded version but not with the original relief values, while 2) ggplot() + geom_spatraster(data=y) + scale_fill_hypso_c() results in a nice colour version but not hillshaded. What I'm looking for is 2) with the hillshaded version of 1) - thanks again.

Comment: I have added that, using base plot.

Comment: You have a full post explaining how to do that also with tidyterra + ggplot2, if you are interested https://dieghernan.github.io/202210_tidyterra-hillshade/

Answer (score 3):

For posterity, leveranging also on `MPB_2022` and Robert, see how you can replicate the same map using `ggplot2` + `tidyterra` (as explained in detail in https://dieghernan.github.io/202210_tidyterra-hillshade/):

```r
library(terra)
library(geodata)
library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)

x <- geodata::elevation_30s("Switzerland", ".")

slope <- terrain(x, "slope", unit = "radians")
aspect <- terrain(x, "aspect", unit = "radians")
hill <- shade(slope, aspect, 40, 270)


# Hillshading, but we need a vector of colors
pal_greys <- hcl.colors(1000, "Grays")

# Get a vector of colors based on the value of shades
# Create index
hill_col <- hill %>%
  # Rename layer
  select(shades = 1) %>%
  mutate(index_col = round(scales::rescale(shades, to = c(1, length(pal_greys))))) %>%
  pull(index_col) %>%
  pal_greys[.]

head(unique(hill_col), 10)

# Plot
ggplot() +
  # Add our hill shade and use fill with the vector color
  geom_spatraster(data = hill, fill = hill_col, maxcell = Inf, alpha = 1) +
  # And add the initial raster with some alpha
  geom_spatraster(data = x) +
  # Add an hypstometric tint
  scale_fill_hypso_tint_c(
    palette = "dem_poster",
    # Need alpha to show the hill
    alpha = 0.5 ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(fill="Elevation")
```

[image]

Comment: Great - thanks also for this solution!